# Unitialized Constant when migrating in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever I try to do a rake db:migrate it stops the migration with the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ModifySiteIdForSpudPermalinks::SpudPermalink
```

The migration file in question is:

```
class ModifySiteIdForSpudPermalinks < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def up
     change_column :spud_permalinks, :site_id, :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
     SpudPermalink.where(:site_id => nil).each {|f| f.site_id = 0 ; f.save}
  end

  def down
     change_column :spud_permalinks, :site_id, :integer, :default => nil, :null => true
     SpudPermalink.where(:site_id => 0).each {|f| f.site_id = nil  ; f.save}
  end
end
```

I thought it might be an issue with the version but it's still an issue with 5.1. Nothing else is standing out to me. Any guidance?

Comment: if you take out the `SpudPermalink.where(:site_id => nil).each {|f| f.site_id = 0 ; f.save}` does it run?

Comment: Yeah stripping out those lines will make it run

Comment: try adding `::` in front of your ActiveRecord query.  so `::SpudPermalink.where(:site_id => nil).each {|f| f.site_id = 0 ; f.save}` and let me know if you get same error

Comment: So I had to do a db:reset for something unrelated and it worked. Really don't get it.